# Fedora 28 not showing up in Grub2 menu after installing Gnome

Tags: grub2

I have an EFI computer dual-booted with Windows and Fedora/Cinnamon. I decided to install Gnome3 on my Fedora partition, and all seemed to be going well until I rebooted my computer. Previously, a few Fedora kernels as well as Windows Boot Manager had appeared in the Grub2 menu, but now, only the Windows Boot Manager shows up.

I am not worried about my files as I have mounted my linux partition (on /dev/sda8) and copied everything in /home. I logged into a live F28 usb to do this.

In my live usb, I tried using `chroot` to get into my Fedora partition and run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. This generated [this file](https://pastebin.com/raw/bqS7v05Z). It appears that my multiple Fedora kernels are in the Grub menu, but when I reboot, only "Windows Boot Manager" appears.

I have also tried reinstalling grub through DNF, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of mounting my root partition, I just mounted my /boot/ partition and generated the grub config file there.